# how can i link the boost library to my project?

Tags: c++, multithreading, qt, boost, boost-thread

i've written the code

```
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/thread/thread.hpp>

using namespace std;

void f1()
{
    cout <<"Hello world, I'm a thread1!"<<endl;
}

int main()
{
    boost::thread t1(&f1);
return 0;
}
```

and added the string in pro file in qt creator

> LIBS += -L/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu  -lboost_system

i've gotten these errors

> build-test_not_qt_1-Desktop-Debug/main.o:-1: In function `boost::detail::thread_data_base::thread_data_base()':
>    /build-test_not_qt_1-Desktop-Debug/main.o:-1: In function`boost::detail::thread_data_base::thread_data_base()':
>    build-test_not_qt_1-Desktop-Debug/main.o:-1: In function `boost::thread::start_thread()':
>    build-test_not_qt_1-Desktop-Debug/main.o:-1: In function`boost::thread::start_thread()':
>    build-test_not_qt_1-Desktop-Debug/main.o:-1: In function `boost::thread::~thread()':
>    build-test_not_qt_1-Desktop-Debug/main.o:-1: In function`boost::thread::~thread()':
>    build-test_not_qt_1-Desktop-Debug/main.o:-1: In function `boost::detail::thread_data<void (*)()>::~thread_data()':
>   /usr/include/boost/thread/detail/thread.hpp:91: error: undefined reference to`boost::detail::thread_data_base::~thread_data_base()'
>   (.rodata._ZTIN5boost6detail11thread_dataIPFvvEEE[_ZTIN5boost6detail11thread_dataIPFvvEEE]+0x10):-1: error: undefined reference to `typeinfo for boost::detail::thread_data_base'
>   :-1: error: collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status

how can I fix them? and how can I make the application working?

Comment: `boost_system` is a boost library for system specific functions. you want `boost_thread`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
LIBS += -L/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu -lboost_system -lboost_thread
```